# NHibernate - The most concise way to select multiple columns using QueryOver

Tags: c#, nhibernate, queryover

With Linq you can easily do:

```
from c in session.Query<Site>()
       select new {c.SiteName, c.SiteId, 
                   c.Network, c.RegionLocation.City, 
                   c.RegionLocation.Region.RegionName};
```

Is there a way to do something like this with `QueryOver`? It seems that you can do it with `SelectList` but that does not seem as clean as linq approach. Is there a cleaner way ?

Answer (score 9):

No not as far as I know, its a bit more verbose then Linq. But isn't this cleanish?

```
session.QueryOver<Sites>()
        .SelectList(x => x
          .Select(p => p.Name)
          .Select(p => p.Lat)
          .Select(p => p.Lng)
        )
        .TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<MarkerDto>())  
        .List<MarkerDto>();  

public class MarkerDto  
{  
  public string Name { get; set; }  
  public decimal? Lat { get; set; }  
  public decimal? Lng { get; set; }  
}
```

If your select list is shared across multiple queries you can attempt to stay dry by using a `projectionBuilder` e.g.

```
Func<QueryOverProjectionBuilder<MarkerDto>, 
    QueryOverProjectionBuilder<MarkerDto>> GetDtoList() {
    MarkerDto dto = null;
    return list => list
      .Select(w => w.Name).WithAlias(() => dto.Name)
      .Select(w => w.Lat).WithAlias(() => dto.Lat)
      .Select(w => w.Lng).WithAlias(() => dto.Lng);
}
```

and use like

```
Session.QueryOver<Sites>()  
    .SelectList(GetDtoList())  
    .TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<MarkerDto>())  
    .List<MarkerDto>();
```

A little bit cleaner but more cumbersome creating a `projectionBuilder`, however why change from Linq if it works for you?

I should also mention that it is possible to create a transformer that transforms into an anonymous type, see this [blog post](http://puredotnetcoder.blogspot.co.uk/2012/04/setresulttransformer-into-anonymous.html), disclaimer mine!

Comment: Nice! Maybe because it is *cleansih* ... change from Linq to QueryOver ;)